# sql server triggers

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

Hello
I need help for creating trigger which would insert id into table1 when table2 filled with row

Comment: You need help or you want it done for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you define a trigger FOR INSERT, you have access to the inserted logical table. You can use it to retrieve the id of the inserted row, and store it in another table.

Something like:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trig
ON table2
FOR INSERT
AS
INSERT INTO table1 (id)
SELECT ins.id FROM inserted ins
GO
```

Comment: Please note that I don't usually like triggers, as for me they have always been a pain to debug.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you [start here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Trigger should be created in the Table 2 insert

> create trigger *< trigger_name >* on
>   *< table_name >* for INSERT AS

*//insert  statement for table1*

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a trigger for that. Use a regular stored procedure.

Comment: Please explain why when you downvote. Triggers that modify data are not good practice other than for exceptional reasons. In this case no justification for using a trigger is explained so the standard advice ought to be not to use a trigger - use a (non-trigger) stored procedure to do the same thing.

Comment: Didn't downvote you, I support your point of view (+1 for this)